# Angular 1.x: attribute of an object inside data-ng-repeat is set as a string, not an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I'm trying to set a value of the `option` field as a JSON object inside another JSON object eg. `catalogue` inside `attribute.catalogue`. The problem is that it is saved as a `String` which looks like a JSON object.

I think this is somehow related to the limitation of the option `value` field. Can I somehow adjust my code, so that the value is stored as a JSON object and not as a String?

This is the code:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <select ng-model="attribute.catalogue" ng-change="showScope()">
        <option data-ng-repeat="catalogue in catalogueObjects"
                value="{{catalogue}}">{{catalogue.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general html `attribute`'s can only store `string` value. In angular world `ng-options` directive does provide an ability to use assign object when select option selected.

```
<select ng-model="attribute.catalogue" ng-change="showScope()"
   data-ng-options="catalogue as catalogue.name for catalogue in catalogueObjects">
</select>
```

#### Reference

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply, but I get this error: `Syntax Error: Token 'in' is an unexpected token at column 16 of the expression [catalogue.name in catalogue] starting at [in catalogue]`

Comment: @DenissM. have a look at edited answer by Hadi, thanks mate :)

Comment: should be `<data-ng-options="catalogue as catalogue.name for catalogue in catalogueObjects">`. This is working correctly. Thanks